# Mark Form as Dirty (Manually) Without ngModel

Tags: forms, angular

I'm using Angular 4.1.3 and came across this requirement and wanted to share my solution to it. Unfortunately the documentation on [www.angular.io](http://www.angular.io) doesn't really list all the available props and methods on system components such as ngForm elements (or at least I couldn't find it).

My requirement was that I needed to have an `<input>` element that was part of a `<form>` that updated the value of its binding only after the **blur** event. Apparently this is only possible without using **[ngModel]** it seems:

```
<form #f="ngForm">
    <input (change)="myVar = $event.target.value" [value]="myVar" />
    <span *ngIf="f.dirty">Form is Dirty!</span>
</form>
```

But since this input isn't bound to an **ngModel** Angular doesn't know it's part of the form. So when the value is changed the form is not marked as **dirty**.

Comment: do you mean without `ngModel` or `[ngModel]` or `[(ngModel)]` or all 3 of them? Because it can be done without `markAsDirty` when using `ngModel`, i.e registering the form controls, since now you are not doing that at all ;) Your current setup won't work if you want to add validation as well...

Comment: @AJT_82 Can you elaborate on how it would work with just **ngModel** because i tried that and it seems like it's binding it to something non existant. And i dont know how i would get it work with [ngModel] and [(ngModel)] since i want the model to be updated on the blur event.

Comment: First, what do you mean by **I want model to be updated on the blur event** Now you have no blur event? :)

Comment: The change event works the same as blur. I can change it to onBlur and it would behave the same. As for model updating, when i bind an input to a field in my component, after each keypress the value in the component is updated. What i want is the component field to be updated when the focus is lost from the input.

Comment: If you want to set form as dirty on blur, I guess you need to set it manually and actually not use a angular form at all, just in the manner you have. Otherwise it will be marked as dirty on first change of form values according to answer below with the "angular form". With that answer you can of course set an blur event and get the value from the input field and do whatever you want with it, hard to say without knowing the usecase.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To solve this you need to manually set the form as dirty and to do that you can use the **markAsDirty()** method on the **ngForm** object like this:

```
<form #f="ngForm">
    <input (change)="myVar = $event.target.value; f.form.markAsDirty();" [value]="myVar" />
    <span *ngIf="f.dirty">Form is Dirty!</span>
</form>
```

Comment: In my case, I also had to call `f.form.updateValueAndValidity()`.

Comment: i did markAsDirty but on the field instead

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** Since using `ngModel` according to comment is not excluded, so as of angular 5 it's possible to use `ngModel` and add `{ updateOn: blur }` and then check the form is dirty:

```html
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="logForm(f.value)">
  <label>Username</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" ngModel #userName="ngModel" [ngModelOptions]="{ updateOn: 'blur' }">
</form>

<p *ngIf="f.form.dirty">Form is Dirty!</p>
```

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kxaebr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

---

**ORIGINAL:**

You need to register the form control with `name` attribute and `ngModel`. Now each control where you have marked an (unique) `name` value and `ngModel` means that it is now registered as a form control.

Furthermore you need to inspect the controls state by exporting `ngModel` to a local template variable, e.g like `#someRef="ngModel"`. Now we can also do validations on this form control and at the same time, since Angular is following the state of this control, Angular can see that the form is dirty (among other things).

For example using the above we can have a (stripped down) form like this:

```html
<form #f="ngForm">
  <label>Username</label>
  <input name="username" ngModel #userName="ngModel">
</form>

<span *ngIf="f.dirty">Form is Dirty!</span>
```

Comment: This doesn't address my initial requirement. I need the bound variable, in your example "username", to only get updates once the user clicks away from the textbox (blur event).